# MySQL: Select multiple values from a table based on multiple values from another table

Tags: mysql

I would like to return all the reports that are about each of these regions, that belong to a macroregion...

I would like to somehow

```
SELECT DISTINCT report FROM reports WHERE region = 
(SELECT distinct region from macroregions where macroregion = 'Africa')
```

The regions in the macroregion are Sahara, West Africa, Tropical Africa,... etc

Although this is impossible since it the subquery would return multiple results.

Comment: @RVWard How is this related to php?

Comment: I am filtering reports to show to the user based on which continent they are on.

Comment: @RVWard I removed the php tag from the question because what language you use to show the results has nothing to do what you are actually asking.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: @RVWard Don't worry about it :) It's just a way to better sort questions and get better and quicker answers. Your question could be answered by Java devs, Ruby devs, Perl devs, really any dev who uses a db but they will probably don't come check out the question because they might think that is for PHP devs only.

Comment: Ohh I see what you are saying. That make sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT report FROM reports WHERE 
region IN 
(SELECT distinct region from macroregions where macroregion = 'Africa')
```

Maybe you missed `IN` operator

Comment: Wow, that worked. So `IN` is the trick to getting around the 'More than one result returned for subquery' error?

Comment: Yes. there are other operator that can do other magic too (like > ANY)

Comment: When i first found out on subquery and the IN operator I felt like you in this moment. Anyway if my answer answered you think to +1 or pick answer ^^

Comment: I'm gonna :) But, I have to wait for a few minutes.

Comment: @rvward consider too that I believe this subquery is faster than a JOIN because JOIN are known to be very exspensive

Comment: JOINs are not expensive. JOINS are cheap.

Comment: @yes123, @RVWard: and you don't really need the `DISTINCT` in the subquery. You probably don't need the first DISTINCT either, unless there are rows with same `report` and `region` in table `reports`.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you what you need:

```
SELECT 
    r.report
FROM
    reports r
INNER JOIN
    macroregions m ON 
        m.region = r.region
        AND 
        m.macroregion = 'Africa'
```

This is all of the reports associated to regions associated to the macroregion 'Africa'.